# Angular boolean shifting betwen defined and undefined

Tags: angularjs, typescript

Im using angular and typescript and im getting a very weird result on some booleans shifting its value from defined to undefined with each cycle.

```
class AnsokanController{

    finnsNr: boolean = false;

    constructor(
        console.log('CTOR Start. finnsNr: ' + this.finnsNr);

        const ansokan = ansokanService.ansokan;
        if (!ansokan) {       
            return;
        } else {
            this.finnsNr = true;
        }

        console.log('CTOR end. finnsNr: ' + this.finnsNr);
    }
}   

class HanteraAnsokanController extends AnsokanController {  

//content emitted cause not relevant
}

// this view uses HanteraAnsokanController
     <ombud finns-nr="!vm.finnsNr">
     </ombud>

// Ombud directive declaration
      <input id="ort"   
             ng-disabled="vm.skaInaktiveras(vm.finnsNr)" />


// Ombud controller
    skaInaktiveras(finnsNr: boolean): boolean {
        console.log('finnsNr:  ' + finnsNr );
        if (finnsNr === true ) {
            return true;            
        }

        return false;
     }


 // Console log output
 CTOR Start. finnsNr: false
 CTOR end. finnsNr: true
 finnsNr:  false
 finnsNr:  undefined
 finnsNr:  false
 finnsNr:  undefined
 finnsNr:  false
 finnsNr:  undefined
 finnsNr:  false
 finnsNr:  undefined
 finnsNr:  false
 finnsNr:  undefined
 finnsNr:  false
 finnsNr:  undefined
```

Comment: `finnsNr` might not be defined in your Ombud controller. You seem to use `finnsMalNummer` in place of `finnsNr`. Try passing `vm.finnsMalNummer` into your `vm.skaInaktiveras()` method

Comment: That was a typo. Ive Changes it to finns-nr

Comment: Could you provide a Plunkr with the issue then?